# Schema Compare Gets to 75% and Never Finishes, Never Times Out

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a schema comparison within a Visual Studio 2010 Database project.  The top bar of the window indicates "Comparing the source and target schemas...", gets to around 75%, and stops progressing.  I have left it to process for over an hour, and have restarted the IDE with no results.  In a separate project in the solution, I am connecting to a different database within the same SQL Server (2008 R2) and I have no problems.  This other database is slightly larger than the problematic one, and loads in under 20 seconds.  I am connecting to a remote server and I've verified that the connection tests OK.  I've also tried to generate a log file using devenv.exe /log c:\working, but no report is created.

Any idea what else I can try to make this work?

Thanks very much,

~DJ

I've verified via SQL Profiler that Visual Studio is successfully downloading the schema from the server.  It seems that VS has a problem with the schemas it is receiving, but without an error message I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an open transaction? `DBCC OPENTRAN` will tell you.

Comment: I stopped and restarted the Schema Comparison, ran this command against the same database via Management studio, and received No active open transactions.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen to me and the problem was that errors were getting sent to the Output window, and I never noticed them, because I assumed the compare never finished because the UI never updated itself.

Comment: I had thought that was my problem as well, but I don't have a bit of output generating while I run the comparison, which baffles me.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your process that gets the database information is being blocked by another SQL Server process.  You can start by running the following command in a new query window while connected to the SQL Server:

```
EXEC sp_who2
```

This will show a list of processes running on the SQL Server.  Look at the `BlkBy` column and see if any rows have a number for a value.  Processes that are blocked will have the session ID of the blocking process in this column.

Blocking processes must release resource (e.g., data pages) locks before your process can use the resource.  This usually occurs through normal processing, but you may have some process that is holding the lock for too long.

Comment: Of the 37 processes that appear, none have any value for the BlkBy